# Xtext define Types for Terminals

Tags: syntax-highlighting, xtext

I am looking for a way to define types for terminals in Xtext so I can generate a different SyntaxHighlighting.

Consider the following part of a grammar:

```
terminal NUMBER: ('0'..'9')+;
terminal TIMES: '*';
terminal PLUS: '+';
```

I want to highlight times and plus different to number. How can this be done? My current plan was to give different types to the terminals so I can distinguish them in the syntax highlighting.

Comment: i dont understand your question. lexical highlighting is based on terminals anyway (AbstractAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper.) In Semantic Highlighting you traverse the node model which gives you the information which rules is used as well.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Thanks for your reply. We found a solution for this. We only had a Grammar object that contained rules. The rules were only Strings. So we could not check which terminal it was, but figured it out.